# How to change BLE device name from iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to change BLE device name within the iOS app.

Currently I have done these things:

1. Scanned
2. Connected to the BLE which I want to change
3. Discovered it's services & characteristics

But then to change it's name I am not sure, what I can do? I have checked other questions but which doesn't guarantees to help.

It requires to pass a new name with a "name" parameter to the device.

Currently, I am doing this thing sure it;s a crap:

```
[peripheral writeValue:@"new name of the device" forCharacteristic:[peripheral.services firstObject] type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I am lacking with knowledge:

here we're not passing any parameter, did we?

Please help.

Comment: You are trying to pass "new name of the device" to "[peripheral.services firstObject]"... But this can only happen if the characteristic is writable (and is an actual characteristic).

Comment: Yes, it's a writable property, that I have checked. But the problem is different, I am not sure, where the "name" filed should go with? I don't write any code for that stuff. [peripheral.services firstObject] is just a peripheral which is currently connected. Can you guide me more?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the actual peripheral name or the name of a service or characteristic that it has?

Comment: Actual peripheral name.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit on which type of peripheral you are talking about, e.g., custom embedded device, another iOS device, etc. . The peripheral name is actually determined from the advertising data that every peripheral can broadcast. So if you want to change the name you need to make sure that the actual peripheral is able to change the advertising packet. Therefore, the peripheral needs to provide a mechanism, e.g., a special characteristic.

Comment: @JensMeder:  There may be two types of names associated with a peripheral: one that the device advertises and another that the device publishes in its database as its BLE GAP device name, although this property may contain either type of name, the GAP device name takes priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer the document or check with the manufacturer if they allow overriding the peripheral name. If allowed, then at what location.

Comment: Manufacturer are not providing any support or SDK for the same.

Comment: The one I've worked with doesn't allow to override the name.

Comment: Sure. Here is it: bhavukjain.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation for [writeValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue?language=objc) because that isn't even close to what the actual parameters are supposed to be.

1. Value is supposed to be NSData, not a string.  Call  dataUsingEncoding: on your string and pass in the correct encoding value (likely ascii or utf8: check your device documentation).

   2. Characteristic is a CBCharacteristic but you are passing in a CBService

Comment: Hi, #2 – It's a typo. Sorry about that. I am passing a CBCharacteristic only.

Comment: Are you actually enumerating the services and the characteristics and checking that the uuid's of the services and characteristic match the values that you are looking for? If not you may be trying to write to the wrong one.  Also you are asking for a response with CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse.  Are you getting a value or an error back in you peripheral delegate didWriteValueFor method?

Comment: Currently, there's only one device. So no need to check for that. :)